# Add HTML or Text programmatically into a CKEDITOR 5 Instance?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

Is there any method to insert text or HTML into the editor programmatically?
I would like to insert a video, which I drag and drop into an editor instance. It works perfectly with images and links, where I do the following:

```
editor.document.listenTo(editor.plugins.get('Clipboard'), 'inputTransformation', (evt, data) => {

var diskFile = data.content.getChild(0).getAttribute("file");
var fName = data.content.getChild(0).getAttribute("filename");
var image = data.content.getChild(0).getAttribute("image");
var nodeType = data.content.getChild(0).getAttribute("nodetype");
var folderId = data.content.getChild(0).getAttribute("folderid");

if (nodeType == 1) {

    if (image == "true") {
        // works perfectly (change to image with src)
        data.content.getChild(0).name = "img";
        data.content.getChild(0).setAttribute("src", "/DAM/Home/DownloadFile?guid=" + diskFile);
     }
     else if (fName.indexOf(".mp4") !== -1) {
         console.log("video");
         // something like this? -> editor.data.insertContent("<video>...</video>");
      }
      else {
          // works perfectly (link with href)
          data.content.getChild(0).setAttribute("href", "/DAM/Home/DownloadFile?guid=" + diskFile);
        }
} else if (nodeType == 0){
    data.content.getChild(0).setAttribute("href", "folder:" + folderId);
}
});
```

I can programmatically change the inserted data to an img or set the anchor href. So I thought I could insert some HTML manually to add a video.

Comment: Have you tried using the 'Video Embed' plugin for your ckeditor?

Comment: There is only a video embed plugin for ckeditor 4. I haven't found anything for ckeditor 5 (https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5)

Comment: seems from the documentation of ckeditor5 that if you want to use third party plugins that where available for ckeditor4 (like the video embed) that you are gonna have to rewrite them from scratch. They have a manual on how to do this on there page under plugins. I suggest taking a look and see how far this is possible for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will try this approach, this is the link btw: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html#creating-a-simple-plugin. Thanks for your help